# Predefined values for ACL action, for common user groups

Tags: development, component, acl, custom-action

Example, I have the action in access.xml:

```
<action name="com_something.someaction" title="someaction" />
```

And I want to set it to "Allow for the Public User group" by default.

I there a simple way to do it, without putting the values directly to the database using the installation script?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but from what I understand, if a custom action is not set then it defaults to allow.

Comment: There is a PR open to allow default actions https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/7517.

Answer (score 1):

The Controller is the final responsible to check for ACL actions. If you override and implement your own logic, you can disable the check or implement a different control.

For example, a disabled ACL check in a re-implemented JControllerForm allowAdd method:

```
protected function allowAdd($data = array())
{
    // $user = JFactory::getUser();
    // return ($user->authorise('core.create', $this->option) || count($user->getAuthorisedCategories($this->option, 'core.create')));

    // Everyone can add
    return true;
}
```

Comment: all this is right, but it's not the thing that I looking for :) ... I want to use "rule" field, so user can configure access, but I cannot define default value for custom actions, like: Manager = "allow", Registered = "Allow"

Comment: In Fof, you can define fof.xml: <view name="object"><acl><task name="browse">core.edit.own</task><task name="batch">core.edit.state</task><task name="process">core.edit.state</task><task name="purge">core.manage</task></acl></view>